# How can a string be casted to an Integer?

Tags: java, generics, typecasting-operator

```
    LinkedList<Integer> adjMatrix[] = new LinkedList[10];
    Object[] temp = (Object[]) adjMatrix;
    LinkedList<String> string = new LinkedList<String>();
    string.add("abc");
    temp[3] = string;
    System.out.println(adjMatrix[3].get(0));
    //prints abc

    //====================================================

    LinkedList<String>[] stringList = new LinkedList[10];
    Object[] oa = (Object[]) stringList;
    LinkedList<Integer> listInt = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    listInt.add(new Integer(3));
    oa[1] = listInt;
    System.out.println(stringList[1].get(0));
    // gives ClassCastException java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I'm kind of confused what exactly happened in the first case, an integer accepted a string value but it didn't happen in the second case. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's pretty simple. When you cast types, you tell the compiler to ignore its usual rules. `println` expects a string argument. In the first case, `adjMatrix[3].get(0)` really is a `String`, so even though the compiler wasn't enforcing the rules, you did, and all is well. In the second case, you've used type casts to lie to the compiler. It generated code as though the left hand operand of `+` in `stringList[1].get(0)+""` is a `String`, but it's really an `Integer`. You can't cast an `Integer` to a `String`. Therefore that code throws.

Comment: I modified the String data type to Double and added 150.58 as a value. It prints exactly the same value! Bytecode is generated without cast checks if it is an Integer type, so it's just honoring everything I fed in!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you're just printing `adjMatrix[3].get(0)`. The compiler thinks that this expression is an Integer. But the actual type doesn't matter: the generated byte-code is

```
  37: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/util/LinkedList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  40: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

So it just passes the object it got from the list to `PrintStream.println(Object)`, which then calls `String.value()` on this object. The compiler never adds a cast to the byte-code, because it's not necessary.

In the second case, you print `stringList[1].get(0)+""`, which the compiler thinks it's a concatenation of a String with the empty String. So the generated byte-code is

```
 101: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/util/LinkedList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
 104: checkcast     #14                 // class java/lang/String
 107: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
 110: ldc           #16                 // String 
 112: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
 115: invokevirtual #17                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
 118: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

As you see, there is a checkcast instruction here, because the bytecode needs to call `StringBuilder.append(String)`, and the expression thus needs to be cast to a String. Since it's actually an Integer, it throws a ClassCastException.

Comment: Hi Nizet, thank you for sharing your thoughts, 
I removed the string appender, now the corresponding byte code is as follows:

  `107: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/util/LinkedList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;

       110: checkcast     #44                 // class java/lang/String

       113: invokevirtual #46                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

Cast check shows up in bytecode only if it's String, doesn't matter if I append it or not.

Comment: Because PrintStream has two overloaded println() methods: one taking a String as argument (and thus used in that case since the expression is supposed to be a String), and one taking an Object as argument (and used in the first case, since the expression is supposed to be an Integer).

Answer (score 2):

The first example create a corrupted array. This is why you get warning when trying to use arrays of generics, because the JVM cannot enforce type safety.

Remember, because of type erasure, `LinkedList<Integer> adjMatrix[]` is actually a `LinkedList adjMatrix[]` at runtime, i.e. it can store all object types.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but why am I not seeing any exception in the first case? I created corrupted arrays in both the scenarios.

Comment: Because you're calling `println(Object)`, so no need to cast value of `adjMatrix[3].get(0)`.